# GetButtonDown and Up wont continue when Im holding my button down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I use the function GetButtonDown/Up it will still only display ones, although I want the button to hold and this function to stop working on release.

```
    private void crouch()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("crouch"))
        {
            float slideSpeed = targetVelocity * 0.6f;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(slideSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("crouch"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
```

I tried a workaround but it did not work, I think this code should work...

Comment: It works exactly as it is intended and [documented](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html) .. You probably rather want [`GetButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.GetButtonDown` “Returns true during the frame the user pressed down the virtual button identified by buttonName” (and only that one frame). What you want is [Input.GetButton()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html) which returns true on every frame while the button is depressed.

You can continue to use `Input.GetButtonUp()` to reset the object once the button is released — unless that also needs to be executed every frame while the button is not depressed, in which case you could just use an else statement after `Input.GetButton()`.

Alternately you could set your own boolean inside the `Input.GetButtonDown()` and `Input.GetButtonUp()` if statements and use that to manage the per-frame actions.